# Union query does not work

Tags: union, visual-foxpro

I am using vfp9.

I have two tables:

```
Countries with the field:
id
--
1
2
3

Students with the fields:
id  nname  nation1id   nation2id   nation3id
--------------------------------------------
1   A         2            1  
2   B         1
3   C         2            3          1

I want a query with this output:
countryid    nname   dummy
--------------------------
1             B        1
1             A        2
1             C        3
2             A        1
2             C        1
3             C        2
```

In other words, for country with id 1 I want to list the people who has it as nation1id first, then those who has it as nation2id, and last those who has it as nation3id. Then I will do the same for country with id 2, and so on.

I have tried this query:

```
 select countries.id from countries ;
 (SELECT nname, 1 FROM students WHERE nation1id = countries.id ;
 UNION ;
 select nname, 2 FROM students WHERE nation2id = countries.id ;
 UNION ;
 select nname, 3 FROM students WHERE nation3id = countries.id ;
 order by 2)
```

but get "Command contains unrecognized phrase/keyword" error message.

Regards,

Jan Nordgreen

Answer (score 0):

missing your country table columns, but the failure is because you have two tables listed... your countries, and your (select/union), but no comma between them or JOIN condition.
As for your countries table not listing fields, I'm sure you are looking for the nation's name, but have "nname" in the student's table and don't know if that is correct or not from my perception.  Anyhow, you could get the output of your query as below.

```
select ;
      allStNat.Nation as CountryID,;
      allStNat.nname,;
      allStNat.NationSort ;
   from ;
      ( SELECT nname, ;
               nation1id as Nation, ;
               1 as NationSort;
           FROM students ;
          WHERE nation1id > 0;
        UNION ALL;
        select nname, ;
               nation2id as Nation,;
               2 as NationSort;
           FROM students ;
          WHERE nation2id > 0;
        UNION ALL;
        select nname, ;
               nation3id as Nation,;
               3 as NationSort ;
           FROM students ;
          WHERE nation3id > 0 ) allStNat;
   order by ;
      1, 3, 2
```

If there was other content from the countries table you wanted, I would alter only slightly by adding the actual country's name and adjusting the order by clause since there is an additional column in the list.

```
select ;
      allStNat.Nation as CountryID,;
      c.Country,;
      allStNat.nname,;
      allStNat.NationSort ;
   from ;
      ( same select/union query above ) allStNat;
         JOIN Countries c ;
            ON allStNat.Nation = c.id
   order by ;
      1, 4, 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have added the fields to the first table in my question. The nname is the nick name of the student. The name of the country is in countries.country while the id of the country is stored in nation1id etc.

Comment: Glad to help... BTW, as a newbie, check the help/tour page.  Marking questions a up and checked help others know what worked and solved a given question, also helps others not waste time on questions already resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the problem has not been resolved. I have two tables countries and students. When I have a working solution I will post back.

Comment: @JanNordgreen, I revised the query to your countries.country column name.  As for the original post of data, I ran the query with the sample data as provided, and the first query DID run and get the correct results.  As for the second query, I just added the join to get the country name.  You can change the order by to suit your needs.